# VBScript Syntax Highlighting in Web Page

Tags: vbscript, google-code-prettify

Single Code Comment for Visual Basic Script (VBScript) seems to be not working , i am using 
Google-code-prettify

https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

For more details please see this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/dekajp/27skU/1/

```
    <div>
     <pre class="prettyprint lang-vb">
        ' Variable Declaration 

        Dim szToken
        Dim oXMLHTTP
        Dim szBaseUri, szUri

        szToken  ="Please see Logon code example for how to obtain a Token"

        ' set the base URI path
 </pre>
</div>
```

Looks like the single quote comment is not working or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the tool. I am familiar with VB and VB.net you're using but see if this syntax works better for you. AHH... also... you can't use ' unless you're using straight VB programming. You must exit your ' with an addition ' at the end. Looking at Fiddle... all your Declarations and szToken were all highlighted as comments.

```
 <div>
 <pre class="prettyprint lang-vb">
    <!--Variable Declaration-->

    Dim szToken as String
    Dim oXMLHTTP
    Dim szBaseUri, szUri

    szToken.text  = ("Please see Logon code example for how to obtain a Token")

    <!--set the base URI path-->
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried to update the jsfiddle with your code, it did not work. can you try ?

Comment: Other workarounds are using Rem or '' for comments (that's two single quotation marks).

Comment: I added the proper HTML comment syntax... `<!-- Something Here -->`

Comment: @SteveKline you do not need those comments .please see my above fiddle link

Comment: Sorry, it just clicked... Never heard of the Prettyprint before now. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation. I removed run-prettify.js script and added prettify.js + lang-vb.js, and it helped. It's still not perfect, so I'm figuring out how to modify it, but. Comments are working great.